# swagger-codegen client: How to include jackson annotations on models

Tags: java, rest, jackson, swagger-codegen

I'm using swagger-codegen to generate a rest client, but I get a problem, the service I'm consuming returns a model with an inheritance, the API model looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private List<Book> books;
    ...
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "typeClass")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Magazine.class) })
public class Book 
{
    //some prop
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "typeClass")
public class Magazine extends Book
{
    //some prop
}
```

The API model is annotated with jackson annotations to deal with inheritance. The API works ok. 
When I generate the client, the client models don't have the jackson annotations, so when I use the generated client to consume the API, it always deserializate using the Book class. It doesn't "see" the Magazine class. I think it's because the generated model does'nt have the jackson annotations to deal with inheritance.

How can I config the swagger-codegen to add the jackson annotations to the model.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Looking at [the code for java](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/JavaClientCodegen.java) and the [templates](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/Java/typeInfoAnnotation.mustache), you need to do something that adds the `jackson` property into the additional properties. Look `additionalProperties.put("jackson", "true");` in the first link and figure out how to get that

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using

```
    java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
   -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json   
    -l java
    -o samples/client/petstore/java
```

you can work with

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
-i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json   
-l spring
-o samples/client/petstore/java
```

Through the language change they also swap out gson to Jackson.

In your case you wwould have something like

```
import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import io.swagger.model.Category;
import io.swagger.model.Tag;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

/**
 * Pet
 */
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2020-06-04T13:33:18.844+02:00")




public class Pet   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Long id = null;

  @JsonProperty("category")
  private Category category = null;

  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name = null;

  @JsonProperty("photoUrls")
  @Valid
  private List<String> photoUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

  @JsonProperty("tags")
  @Valid
  private List<Tag> tags = null;
      ...
```

source: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5785

When you build the client with Generator.Swagger (https://generator.swagger.io/ the online swagger Codegen api:/gen/clients/{language}) then you can look through the settings in /gen/clients/{language} or https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/ and build your request up to that.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line of code in your plugin configuration in pom.xml

<'library>$libraryValue<'/library>

$libraryValue can be based on which library you are using in your dependencies. Either jersey one if you are using Jersey 1.x.x or jersey2 if you are using Jersey 2.x.x.

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/3695939/moondaisy for the headstart that you have provided.