# Deserialization of generated sub-class results in the parent object

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

*Versions: Swagger-codegen (v3): 3.0.11 | Jackson: 2.9.8*

I currently generate my classes from a `swagger.yaml` file (indentation may differ due to double copy-paste):

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "servicename"
  version: "1.0"
  title: "servicename"
schemes:
  - "http"
  - "https"
paths:

definitions:
  Notification:
    type: "object"
    discriminator: "typeOfNotification"
    properties:
      typeOfNotification:
        description: "Type of notification"
        enum:
          - "EMAIL"
          - "SMS"
        default: "EMAIL"
  EmailNotification:
    allOf:
    - $ref: "#/definitions/Notification"
    - type: "object"
      properties:
        name:
          type: "string"
          example: "Name of reciever"
          description: "Name of the receiver"
        emailAddress:
          type: "string"
          example: "info@stackoverflow.com"
          description: "Email address of the receiver"
```

Which generates two classes:

Notification.java

```
package nl.test;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * Notification
 */

@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2019-09-26T16:01:12.401+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]")
public abstract class Notification {
  /**
   * Type of notification
   */
  @JsonAdapter(TypeOfNotificationEnum.Adapter.class)
  public enum TypeOfNotificationEnum {
    EMAIL("EMAIL"),
    SMS("SMS");

    private String value;

    TypeOfNotificationEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    public static TypeOfNotificationEnum fromValue(String text) {
      for (TypeOfNotificationEnum b : TypeOfNotificationEnum.values()) {
        if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
    public static class Adapter extends TypeAdapter<TypeOfNotificationEnum> {
      @Override
      public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final TypeOfNotificationEnum enumeration) throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.value(enumeration.getValue());
      }

      @Override
      public TypeOfNotificationEnum read(final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        String value = jsonReader.nextString();
        return TypeOfNotificationEnum.fromValue(String.valueOf(value));
      }
    }
  }  @SerializedName("typeOfNotification")
  private TypeOfNotificationEnum typeOfNotification = null;

  public Notification typeOfNotification(TypeOfNotificationEnum typeOfNotification) {
    this.typeOfNotification = typeOfNotification;
    return this;
  }


  @Schema(description = "Type of notification")
  public TypeOfNotificationEnum getTypeOfNotification() {
    return typeOfNotification;
  }

  public void setTypeOfNotification(TypeOfNotificationEnum typeOfNotification) {
    this.typeOfNotification = typeOfNotification;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Notification notification = (Notification) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.typeOfNotification, notification.typeOfNotification);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(typeOfNotification);
  }
}
```

And the EmailNotification:

```
package nl.test;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import java.io.IOException;
import nl.test.Notification;
/**
 * EmailNotification
 */

@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2019-09-26T16:01:12.401+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]")
public class EmailNotification extends Notification {
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name = null;

  @SerializedName("emailAddress")
  private String emailAddress = null;

  public EmailNotification name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Name of the receiver
   * @return name
  **/
  @Schema(example = "Name of receiver", description = "Name of the receiver")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public EmailNotification emailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Email address of the receiver
   * @return emailAddress
  **/
  @Schema(example = "test@stackoverflow.com", description = "Email address of the receiver")
  public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
  }

  public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
     EmailNotification = (EmailNotification) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.name, emailNotification.name) &&
        Objects.equals(this.emailAddress, emailNotification.emailAddress) &&
        super.equals(o);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, emailAddress, super.hashCode());
  }

}
```

Which is nice. But now the problem occurs during the deserialization of the JSON. When an ObjectMapper is passed the JSON corresponding to a `User` class, which has one property of type `Notification`, and the JSON is actually of type `EmailNotification`, then for some reason the deserializer doesn't care and deserializes it into a `Notification`, thus ignoring the `emailAddress` property.

Corresponding test class:

```
package nl.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ObjectMappersConfigurationTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"user\": {\n" +
                "    \"notification\": {\n" +
                "      \"name\": \"somename\",\n" +
                "      \"emailAddress\": \"test@stackoverflow.com\",\n" +
                "      \"typeOfNotification\": \"EMAIL\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}\n";

        ObjectMapper mapper = createJsonObjectMapper();
        User order = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    public ObjectMapper createJsonObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        setDefaultRelaxObjectMappings(objectMapper);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    public static void setDefaultRelaxObjectMappings(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);

        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.enable(ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);
    }
}
```

And the output will be:

```
User {
  notification {
     notificationType: EMAIL
  }
}
```

Where I expected:

```
User {
  notification {
     notificationType: EMAIL,
     emailAddress: "...",
     name: "..."
  }
}
```

Now I know that I can use a custom deserializer for this purpose, but this seems like overkill, deserializing objects with inheritance should be a simple setting I suppose. I just can't seem to find it.

Enabling default typing would be an alternative but I'd rather refrain from that since our YAML files come from an external party, forcing them to default type their YAML isn't the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the `@JsonSubType` annotation was missing. And since the `ObjectMapper` does not communicate with swagger, it couldn't ever know that the class should be mapped to a `EmailNotification` and thus would always create a `Notification` object.

Adding:

```
<plugin>
   ....
   <configuration>
     ...
     <library>jersey2</library>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Fixed it, the class annotations for the `Notification` class are now generated as:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SMSNotification.class, name = "SMSNotification"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EmailNotification.class, name = "EmailNotification"),
})
public class Notification {
    ....
```

This adds the mapping which the `ObjectMapper` understands while deserializing.

Special thanks to the answer provided 
here [swagger-codegen client: How to include jackson annotations on models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616922/swagger-codegen-client-how-to-include-jackson-annotations-on-models)

Answer (score 0):

Its still does not work for me. I use gradle plugin open-api-generator v6.1.0 (i tested also with 5.4.0)
Here is my simple swagger :

```
"components": {
"schemas": {
  "Parent": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "vehicle": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Vehicle"
      }
    }
  },
  "Vehicle": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "vehicleType": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "discriminator": {
      "propertyName": "vehicleType",
      "mapping": {
        "CAR": "#/components/schemas/Car",
        "TRUCK": "#/components/schemas/Truck"
      }
    }
  },
  "Car": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Vehicle"
      },
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "carProperty": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Truck": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Vehicle"
      },
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "truckProperty": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

}

and there is my openApiTaskConfiguration (in build.gradle file):

```
generatorName.set("kotlin")
configFile.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/swagger/config.json")
inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/swagger/swagger-test.json")
outputDir.set("$generatedSources")
generateModelTests.set(false)
typeMappings.set(mapOf(
    "Date" to "String"))
configOptions.set(mapOf(
    "enumPropertyNaming" to "UPPERCASE",
    "dateLibrary" to "string",
    "interfaceOnly" to "true",
    "serializableModel" to "true",
    "collectionType" to "array",
    "serializationLibrary" to "jackson"
))
globalProperties.set(mapOf("apis" to "false", "models" to "", "modelDocs" to "false"))
```

}`

The Object Vehicle is generated as an interface but at runtime this is never the class Car or Truck constructor who are called but the interface. And that throw exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8vml.png)